# How does a regex matching work?

Tags: java, regex

This question is a derivation from another question in this forum which I thought was quite simple, but in the end found out a difficult one.

OP asked to replace any text `xyz` from the all substrings `<tagname>xyz</tagname>` with some `NEW TEXT`. I did the following:

```
String str="<tagname>bgerh</tagname>sdfghuhjg<tagname>bgew</tagname>rwesdgrhtf<tagname>bfgh</tagname>";

System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=(<tagname>)).*(?=(</tagname>))","NEW TEXT"));
```

The output I got:

```
<tagname>NEW TEXT</tagname>
```

which is obviously not the desired one.

So, I would like to know if the regex checking happen from both the ends of a string, and I will bbe delighted with a solution to the example.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.*` is a greedy quantifier, meaning it will match everything it can.  Because your sample string begins with `<tagname>` and ends with `</tagname>`, everything in between will be matched by `.*`.

To fix this, you can instead use a reluctant quantifier, and it will only grab as little as it can.  The reluctant qualifier looks like this: `.*?`, and thus the entire expression would look like this:

```
"(?<=<tagname>).*?(?=</tagname>)"
```

Comment: Plus the usual caveat: as soon as you encounter nested tags, everything breaks down. Regex is not the tool to process nested structures like XML.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to remove the unnecessary inner parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd usually do this by excluding `<` from the inner part of the regexp. Like:

```
(?<=<tagname>)[^<]*(?=</tagname>)
```